# Distribute elements of the fist list to another list/array

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an `Array[(List(String)), Array[(Int, Int)]]` like this

```
 ((123, 456, 789), (1, 24))
 ((89, 284), (2, 6))
 ((125, 173, 88, 222), (3, 4))
```

I would like to distribute each element of the first list to the second list, like this

```
 (123, (1, 24))
 (456, (1, 24))
 (789, (1, 24))
 (89, (2, 6))
 (284, (2, 6))
 (125, (3, 4))
 (173, (3, 4))
 (88, (3, 4))
 (22, (3, 4))
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe that this would be a more precisely asked question if you included compilable (via REPL) a *typed* example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For input data defined as follows:

```
val data = Array((List("123", "456", "789"), (1, 24)), (List("89", "284"), (2, 6)), (List("125", "173", "88", "222"), (3, 4)))
```

you can use:

```
data.flatMap { case (l, ii) => l.map((_, ii)) }
```

which yields:

```
Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array(("123", (1, 24)), ("456", (1, 24)), ("789", (1, 24)), ("89", (2, 6)), ("284", (2, 6)), ("125", (3, 4)), ("173", (3, 4)), ("88", (3, 4)), ("222", (3, 4)))
```

which I believe matches what you are looking for.

Comment: Dear Shadowlands, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, it seemed to me that you were using a single type.

```
scala> val xs: List[(List[Int], (Int, Int))] = 
     |   List( ( List(123, 456, 789), (1, 24) ), 
     |         ( List(89, 284), (2,6)), 
     |         ( List(125, 173, 88, 222), (3, 4)) )
xs: List[(List[Int], (Int, Int))] = List((List(123, 456, 789), (1,24)),
                                         (List(89, 284),(2,6)),
                                         (List(125, 173, 88, 222),(3,4)))
```

Then I wrote this function:

```
scala> def f[A](xs: List[(List[A], (A, A))]): List[(A, (A, A))] = 
     |     for {
     |       x    <- xs
     |       head <- x._1
     |     } yield (head, x._2)
f: [A](xs: List[(List[A], (A, A))])List[(A, (A, A))]
```

Apply `f` to `xs`.

```
scala> f(xs)
res9: List[(Int, (Int, Int))] = List((123,(1,24)), (456,(1,24)), 
             (789,(1,24)), (89,(2,6)), (284,(2,6)), (125,(3,4)), 
                 (173,(3,4)), (88,(3,4)), (222,(3,4)))
```